# C# La llamada es ambigua entre los siguientes métodos o propiedades: 'Math.Ceiling(decimal)' y 'Math.Ceiling(double)'

Tags: c#, .net, math

ciertamente no lo encuentro alguien si?

```
int ancho = 276;
string Business_name = "Hola alguien encuentra esto?";
int divisor = ancho == 276 ? 16 : 9;

double altoi = Math.Ceiling((double)Business_name.Length / (double)divisor);
```

error CS0121 La llamada es ambigua entre los siguientes métodos o propiedades: 'Math.Ceiling(decimal)' y 'Math.Ceiling(double)'

editado

### cambiando he cambiado la forma supongo que es por eso que sucede

desde otra clase externa a Formpruebaservice estoy realizando muchas acciones entre ellas esta:

enviar una peticion para impresion.

```
public clase asfsafsa {...

    Formpruebaservice enviar_datos = new Formpruebaservice();
    enviar_datos.Cargar_imprmir(objetoimp);
    enviar_datos.printcuartos.Print();
}
public partial class Formpruebaservice : Form
{
   public string Business_name;
   public PrintDocument printcuartos;


   public Formpruebaservice()
      {
      InitializeComponent();
      Prueba();

       public void Prueba()
        {
            
            #region
            this.printcuartos = new PrintDocument();
            PrinterSettings pstwo = new PrinterSettings();
            printcuartos.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
            printcuartos.PrinterSettings = pstwo;
            printcuartos.PrintPage += Imprimircuartos;
            #endregion

        }

      public void Cargar_imprmir(dynamic objeto){
         this.Business_name= objeto.Business_name;
      }

     public void Imprimircuartos(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
     {
     int ancho = 276;
     int divisor = ancho == 276 ? 16 : 9;
    
     double altoi = Math.Ceiling((double)Business_name.Length / (double)divisor);

     ...
     ...


     }
      


    }
}
```

Comment: Un poco raro, según https://dotnetfiddle.net/cdFdh6 se ve bien, sin error.

Comment: puede ser un problema de precision.. proba castear todo el contendio a decimal o doble...

Comment: Te sugiero limpies y construyas nuevamente tu proyecto, como comenta fredyfx no tienes algún error en el código.

Comment: dale gracias por su tiempo señores voy a por ello